# Running Genie.jl Docker container - ArgumentError: invalid base 10 digit 't' in "true"

Tags: docker, julia

I am trying to run a web app built with Genie.jl in a Docker container. I am using the Genie.Deploy package.

I have:

1. Created a Dockerfile using `Genie.Deploy.Docker.dockerfile()`
2. Built the Docker container using `Genie.Deploy.Docker.build()`

But when I try to run the app from the container, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: LoadError: ArgumentError: invalid base 10 digit 't' in "true"
Stacktrace:
  [1] tryparse_internal(#unused#::Type{Int64}, s::String, startpos::Int64, endpos::Int64, base_::Int64, raise::Bool)
    @ Base ./parse.jl:137
  [2] parse(::Type{Int64}, s::String; base::Nothing)
    @ Base ./parse.jl:241
  [3] parse
    @ ./parse.jl:241 [inlined]
  [4] execute(config::Genie.Configuration.Settings; server::Nothing)
    @ Genie.Commands ~/.julia/packages/Genie/35M8N/src/Commands.jl:21
  [5] #run#31
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Genie/35M8N/src/Genie.jl:231 [inlined]
  [6] top-level scope
    @ ~/app/genie.jl:35
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:386
  [8] include
    @ ~/app/src/Swestats.jl:1 [inlined]
  [9] main()
    @ Main.Swestats ~/app/src/Swestats.jl:8
 [10] top-level scope
    @ ~/app/src/Swestats.jl:12
 [11] include
    @ ./client.jl:444 [inlined]
 [12] main()
    @ Main ~/app/bootstrap.jl:6
 [13] top-level scope
    @ ~/app/bootstrap.jl:5
in expression starting at /home/genie/app/genie.jl:35
in expression starting at /home/genie/app/src/Swestats.jl:1
in expression starting at /home/genie/app/bootstrap.jl:5
```

All of the controllers are compiling as the should, I can run the app outside the container without problems. Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Presumably there is the string `"true"` instead of the value `true` somewhere, maybe in the container's config.